# Lync 2013 SDK GetContactInformation Photo

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, skype, lync

i'm currently trying to show contacts pictures of Lync users in my application. Works well, but only if the user was looked up before in Lync client. There seems to be some sort of caching needed. Without looking it up before or having the user as direct contact in the contact list, it returns nothing. Any ideas how to do the lookup by code? Thats what i'm doing right now:

```
Public Function GetLyncPicture(lyncMail As String) As Image
    Dim myimage As Image = Nothing

    Try
        If lyncMail.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            client = LyncClient.GetClient()

            If client IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim cManager As ContactManager = client.ContactManager

                If cManager IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim contact As Contact = cManager.GetContactByUri(lyncMail)
                    If contact IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim ciList As New List(Of ContactInformationType)()
                        ciList.Add(ContactInformationType.Photo)
                        Dim dic As IDictionary(Of ContactInformationType, Object) = Nothing
                        dic = contact.GetContactInformation(ciList)

                        If dic IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim photoStream As Stream = TryCast(dic(ContactInformationType.Photo), Stream)

                            If photoStream IsNot Nothing Then
                                myimage = Image.FromStream(photoStream)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    GetLyncPicture = myimage
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [ContactSubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.contactsubscription_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx).  For every contact you wish to see the "information" (e.g. photo) for, you add to a contact subscription and you will be called back whenever the information you wish to have is available or changed. Microsoft provide a [howto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937284.aspx) in using contact subscriptions.

So there is no way to get the image "now".  It can take a while for a photo to show up.  So it's better to display what you have and update whenever you get a callback.